# How do I add a KML layer to Google Maps using the capacitor/google-maps plugin

Tags: google-maps, capacitor

I am using the @capacitor/google-maps plugin to add a map to an ionic app with the following code.

```
  import { GoogleMap, Marker } from '@capacitor/google-maps';

  async createMap() {
    const mapsKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    this.map = await GoogleMap.create({
      forceCreate: true,
      id: 'map',
      element: this.mapRef.nativeElement,
      apiKey: mapsKey,
      config: {
        center: this.mapLoc,
        zoom: this.mapZoom,
      },
    });
    await this.addMarkers();
  }
  
  async addMarkers() {
    const markers: Marker[] = [
      {
        coordinate: { lat: 50.90778268021916, lng: -114.10515149551082, },
        title: 'My House',
        snippet: "'Best place on earth'"
      },
      {
        coordinate: { lat: 50.90778268021980, lng: -114.10515149551000, },
        title: 'random place',
        snippet: "Not sure"
      },
    ];
    
    await this.map.addMarkers(markers);

    this.map.setOnMarkerClickListener(async (marker) => {
      this.openMessage(marker)
    });
  }
```

Angular uses the following to import a KML layer

```
  // google-maps-demo.component.ts
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import {GoogleMap, MapKmlLayer} from '@angular/google-maps';

  @Component({
    selector: 'google-map-demo',
    templateUrl: 'google-map-demo.html',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [GoogleMap, MapKmlLayer],
  })
  export class GoogleMapDemo {
    center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = {lat: 24, lng: 12};
    zoom = 4;

    kmlUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/kml/westcampus.kml';
  }


  <!-- google-maps-demo.component.html -->
  <google-map height="400px" width="750px" [center]="center" [zoom]="zoom">
    <map-kml-layer [url]="kmlUrl" />
  </google-map>
```

I have been going through the @capacitor/google-maps plugin docs and searching online for any info on adding layers to the plugin.  Is this possible or should I just remove the plugin and go Angular in the ionic App?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is presently no way to accomplish this with @capacitor/google-maps plugin.  In fact I found at least 5 bugs with the plugin with existing features.  I will be using @angular/google-maps going forward as it has most of the Google Map features.